# Mysql call stops all forms of output php

Tags: php, mysql

Hello, I'm kind of new to php, so don't bash on me, but I just can't figure out what the problem is with this code. So basically I have several forms of output, but as soon as I do anything with mysql ( even just connect and disconnect! ), it won't allow me to do any kind of output. It also won't allow me to redirect.

I tried taking all the code out between the mysql connect and disconnect code and it didn't help to resolve anything, However, as soon as I comment out the mysql connection code, all my outputs and redirects work! I'm trying to build a simple login script that gets the email and password from a form elsewhere. I would love to get this resolved so I could figure out if the rest of it works. And I know that 'header' will not work after `echo`; the echo and the file writes will not be there as soon as I can make sure this is working. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
<?php
/*
    Login.php searches for the email address given by loginPage.php in the data base.
    If the email is found and the password given by loginPage.php matches that stored 
    in the data base, a session will begin and the client will be redirected to the 
    main page.
    *** INCOMPLETE ***  
*/
echo "HELLO!";
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$errorLog = fopen("login.txt", "w");    
    fwrite($errorLog, "***Sesion started***");
$mysql_id = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12131");
if (!$mysql_id)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
mysql_select_db('informationStation', $mysql_id);

$results = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM Personals WHERE email = '" . $email . "';", $mysql_id);

if($results != null && $password == mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
         $redirect  = 'Location: http://127.0.1.1/main.php';
    }
else 
    {
         $redirect  = 'Location: http://127.0.1.1/loginPage.php';
    {   
mysql_close($mysql_id); 
fwrite($errorLog, "result: " . $results);
fwrite($errorLog, "redirect: " . $redirect); 
fclose($errorLog);
header($redirect);  
?>
```

Comment: Check your server/php error logs and see if anything's crashing, plus turn on all the PHP debugging options: display_error, error_log, etc... Do not work in the dark, turn on all the lights available to you.

Comment: Show us the code you've written and maybe we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get you started..

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM Personals WHERE email = '" . $email . "'", $mysql_id) or die(mysql_error());
```

But you also need to read about sql injection.

And you should not store passwords in your database without salting and hashing them.

And you also need to use array syntax to access the data from your result...

Comment: Wow, thanks for the advice! The only filtering was going to put in this login was Java script. I didn't even think about sql injection! I'll make sure to include a way to stop that in my later versions!

Comment: Also the code you suggested deosn't seem to do anything. The problem is ( ive already experimented with die() ) is that even die() will not display anything when a mysql connection is opened anywhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12131") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('informationStation', $mysql);


function loged($email, $password) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM Personals WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND password='" . $password . "'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 1)
        return false;
    return true;
}


if(loged(mysql_real_escape_string($email), md5($password))) {
    header('Location: http://127.0.1.1/mainPage.php');
    exit;
}   

header('Location: http://127.0.1.1/loginPage.php');
```

In this example you need to store users password using md5 encryption method (search for other more securely encryption methods).

Also we've escaped the email address against sql injection.

I've created a function which can be called every time you want to see if the user is loged in or not.

Note that this is not a complete login script. You will also need to make a login function where you'll have to start a new session for each user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I was going to change mine to look alot like that, but when i figured out I couldn't use header with any mysql  code, it kinda stalled my progress. Also thanks for the encryption method idea, I don't know anything about encryption, so that gives me a good place to start.